# Passing value using an event

Tags: c#, winforms

So, first I generate a List containing custom usercontrols made of a button and progressbar, I generate this using a for loop.

Inside this loop I send each events to the desired methods, now what I need is access to the progress bar inside of the reset method, how do I do that?

```
ProgressTimerList[i].Button.Reset += Button_Reset;
ProgressTimerList[i].Progressbar //////Need access to this object
```

And

```
 void Button_Reset(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //////Inside of here
        }
```

Comment: Does 'Button` have its `Parent` set to the user control? I don't know what framework you are using, but you might be able to do something like this: `((ProgressTimerListType)((Button)sender).Parent).ProgressBar`... This works differently depending on what UI framework you are using, such as Winforms, WPF, ASP, etc...

Comment: And to Ron's point, please tag your question with the framework you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a class inherited from `EventArgs` with a property of type Progressbar and pass it to the handler:

```
public class MyButtonEventArgs : EventArgs{
    public --WhateverProgressbarTypeIs-- Bar {get;set;}
}

ProgressTimerList[i].Button.Reset += (sender, e) => Button_Reset(sender, new MyEventArgs { Bar = ProgressTimerList[i].Progressbar });

void Button_Reset(object sender, MyButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var wunderBar = e.Bar;
}
```

Comment: This was more what I was thinking, but I cant get this to work atm.
the for loop that adds all these buttons is inside of 
this 'private void MainForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)'
making (sender, e) conflict with the already declared versions

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to handle this is to use anonymous methods.

At the point in your code where you are attaching the handler, try this:

```
ProgressTimerList[i].Button.Reset += (s, e) =>
{
    //////Inside of here
    ProgressTimerList[i].Progressbar //////Can access this object
};
```

No need whatsoever for the `Button_Reset` method.

The other nice thing is that this encapsulates the event handling within a method so that other code can't directly call `Button_Reset`. As encapsulation is one of the four pillars of OOP this helps to make your code more robust.

If you need to detach the handler you can do this:

```
EventHandler button_reset = (s, e) =>
{
    //////Inside of here
    ProgressTimerList[i].Progressbar; //////Can access this object
    ///more code
    ///detach
    ProgressTimerList[i].Button.Reset -= button_reset;
};

ProgressTimerList[i].Button.Reset += button_reset;
```

If you have a clash with the name of `e` within your `MainForm_Load` then just call it `e2` instead.

One other gotcha you might hit is that you're accessing items in an array within your event handler. You probably need to capture the variable locally before using it in the handler.

Like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < ProgressTimerList.Count(); i++)
{
    var local_i = i;
    EventHandler button_reset = (s, e) =>
    {
        //////Inside of here
        ProgressTimerList[local_i].Progressbar; //////Can access this object
        ///more code
        ///detach
        ProgressTimerList[local_i].Button.Reset -= button_reset;
    };

    ProgressTimerList[i].Button.Reset += button_reset;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
((ProgressTimerListType)((Button)sender).Parent).ProgressBar
```

Solved it using this thanks to Ron Beyer! Thanks!

If someone is up for more detail can I ask, why do I need to cast the sender before I can use it as a Button, not just use sender.Parent?

Comment: Because sender is an object, and doesn't have a .Parent property. You need to cast it to a button first, you could have also cast it to the more generic `Control` class and gotten the same effect.

Comment: Please mark this corrected answer if it work. Btw, you use "custom usercontrols made of a button and progressbar" so why dont create property/event to access inside it easier like: `public ProgressBar MyProgressBar
        {
            get
            {
                return progressBar1;
            }
            set
            {
                progressBar1 = value;
            }
        }` or `private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }` ?